Why is my Load Delay really high for my LCP in mobile?
I am tweaking my site using PSI and am having an LCP issue.
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-ocoopa-com/zr0gxma1u4?form_factor=mobile

I've tried adding preload, resizing images, nothing reduces the load delay time.
<link rel="preload" as="image" fetchpriority="high" href="//www.ocoopa.com/cdn/shop/files/144.jpg?v=1724060489&width=480" imagesrcset="//www.ocoopa.com/cdn/shop/files/144.jpg?v=1724060489&width=300 300w" />

On the PC side, however, this problem of maximum content rendering is absent.

What is "?v=1724060489&"?

@str1ng This is the version number of the image. If the image is not modified, this string will not change.

Based on the provided info, it's good that you're using fetchpriority, but make sure not to overuse it on the other elements, as you're directly placing those other elements in competition with this one, which significantly affects LCP, another thing you can do is lazy load other stuff that is not so crucial. Also, one more suggestion is trying to use .WEBP image format and serving responsive images i.e. srcset="image-300.webp 300w, image-480.webp 480w, image-800.webp 800w" sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 480px".

If standard image optimization and preloading haven't reduced your LCP, try the following advanced strategies:
Critical CSS and Rendering:
Inline Critical CSS: Inline only the CSS needed for above-the-fold content to prevent render-blocking. Tools like Critical can help extract critical CSS.
Font Loading Optimization: Ensure that fonts are loaded in a way that does not block the rendering of the page. Use font-display: swap; to prevent invisible text during loading.
JavaScript Optimization:
Defer or Asynchronously Load JavaScript: Only load essential JavaScript initially and defer the rest. This reduces the initial rendering time, especially for heavy scripts.
Eliminate Unnecessary JavaScript: Audit your JavaScript bundles to remove unnecessary or duplicate code. Tools like Webpack Bundle Analyzer can help identify heavy bundles.
Server-Side Rendering (SSR):
Pre-render Critical Pages: Use SSR to generate HTML on the server for the critical parts of your pages. This reduces the load on the client and improves the perceived performance.
If you are using wordpress you can use LiteSpeed Cache plugins to solve your issue.
